# JQuery stopPropagation not preventing event bubbling

Tags: jquery, droppable, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I have an application whereby several lists can appear stacked on top of each other. The list items can be swapped between lists via drag/drop. When I drop a list item on a list that is overlying another list I would like the topmost list only to handle the drop event.

Currently my problem is that all event handlers fire regardless of my use of `e.stopPropagation`, `e.preventDefault` or `return false`.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6fLw/6/

Any guidelines greatly appreciated

Comment: This is an old question but it appears high in Google search results. The solution is to set the { greedy: true } property just on the CHILD droppable(). This will prevent propagation to the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug filed about this very thing, there is some code provided by a participant which may be able to help you with a workaround.

[jQuery UI ticket #3452](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3452)

Comment: That looks like the very thing alright. I was hoping to avoid shoehorning a hover method in to get this working but thanks for pointing out the bug ticket.